# Field Size - Kibana search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

My applications are logging request and response payloads as fields in elasticsearch.
Is there a way to retrieve the size (in bytes) of a specific field returned in kibana search?

Comment: "size" as size in bytes?

Comment: Yes , size in bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/6.1/scripted-fields.html) which will return the length of the `payload` field.

The Painless script code would look something like this:

```
params._source.payload.length()
```

Comment: Thanks Val. will check